# How to prove the probability inequation with expectation?

Tags: probability

$X_1$ takes values in $[0,1]$. Let $EX_1=p$. Prove:

$$E(e^{tX_1})\le e^{(e^t-1)p}$$

The Markov Inequality gives the contrary sign and MGF seems not work. Can I directly derive this inequation? Much thanks!

Comment: To take a simple example, if $P(X_1=1)=p$ and $P(X_1=0)=1-p$ then $E[e^{tX_1}] = pe^t+1-p \le e^{(e^t-1)p}$